# How do I store chars and ints in one array

Tags: arrays, c, struct, scanf

I need to write a program in C that reads user input (=data from highway cameras) and then work with them.

**What should the program do:** program gets input data -> stores them -> then the user is able to enter a license plate number, date and time and see if a car with that license plate was seen by some camera at that time.

If **YES**, then it prints out the ID of a camera that saw the car.

If **NOT**, then it prints out the two closest camera records (when it saw it last before entered date and when it saw it next).

I need to read input of a user with this structure:

e.g:

`{10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30,`

`289: XYZ-98-76 Oct 10 15:40,` <- second entry

`25: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 8:50,`

`42: Slartibartfast Dec 21 6:00,`

The **second** entry means:

289 = CameraID

XYZ-98-76 = License plate

Oct = Month

10 = Day in a month

15:40 = Time

The problem is that the license plate can even be a **custom license plate**. In our country, you can pay for custom license plate. These don not have any pattern and can have different length. They can be whatever the customer wants. *e.g: atC12345678, 1A2B592nsjJ, A9235-DsA5-IH8C.* They can contain: uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, dashes.

I do not know how to store the license plate because of the mix of ints and chars.
I am using `struct` to create a structure for every camera record, but the license plate is always a problem because I don't know how to save the input for license plate as one piece.

*(my struct contains int camID, char month, int day, int hour, int minute)*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a limit for the number of characters on custom license plates to deal with?

Comment: Why don't you just store the entire license plate as a cstring?

Comment: ..or use some simple hash?

Comment: Strings: don't confuse "numbers" with "integers". Sherlock Holmes lives at 212b Baker Street so his house number is 212b. Ditto with credit card, phone, zip, PIN etc, they are not integers.